# Can't add library project to my app project?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm creating a new app and I want to use some libraries like this: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

I had downloaded this library, added it to my workspace using New Android Project -> Create from existig source. Went to properties > android, and checked Is Library. Then I went to properties > android in my app project, and clicked add on the Libraries section, and chose the library, and It show me the library with a green V near it. I've clicked ok, but couldn't use the library so I've opened the properties > android again, and there was a red cross near the library, and '?' under the "Project" column.

I can't understand why it's happening! It's really annoying, happened to me when I tried to add facebook API to my app, and I just gave up and copied the source to my project.

Thanks

Comment: Check problems and post them or Post screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy every Library manually inside Eclipse Workspace, before importing it, as Eclipse seems to be silly if the Library lays somewhere else. Also symlinking a Library will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to Delete the library project from Eclipse (but not from disk of course), and Import it again (Import existing Android Code into Eclipse). The problem disappeared then.